# How to make a physics based net in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm new to SceneKit and I'm trying to make a basketball net react to a ball when it falls on the goal.

I'm trying to use hinge joints but that doesn't seem appropriate to the case. I'm considering creating an animation of the net, but a physics solution would be more appropriate.

Thanks

Comment: What code have you tried? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you haven't read it already.